# Как сделать весь SnackBar кликабельным?

Tags: android, android-studio, snackbar

Нужно, чтоб SnackBar скрывался не только по нажатия в нем кнопки ОК, а по нажатия в любом месте SnackBar-а.
Проще говоря нужно сделать весь этот всплывающий блок кликабельным.

Comment: Ил на крайний случай, как в нем кнопку ОК переместить в левую часть экрана?

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете попробовать так

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(this.view, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
        }
});
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо)